# inline form - making the textbox box wider

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have my text boxes longer
I tried putting col-lg-XX on the textbox but it doesn't work. What is the bootstrap way to do this? [see the code](http://www.bootply.com/PW6LqoPNiI)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only label-primary" for="inputUrl">Bookmark To Add</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="inputUrl" placeholder="Enter your bookmark here" />
        </div>                
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>   
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out there was an entry in the site.css that forced a max-width on an input field. This is the case if you start a default ASP.NET MVC project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input class="form-control" id="inputUrl" placeholder="Enter your bookmark here" style="width:500px" />
```

This will change the lenght

[Modified code](http://www.bootply.com/qiel09bKVp)